# Ruby certificate replace mv rename: permission denied

Tags: terminal, command-line-interface

So I tried to update my Ruby certificate and replace the old one with this command:

```
mv cacert.pem /private/etc/ssl/cert.pem
```

then it gives confirmation:

```
override rw-r--r-- root/wheel for /private/etc/ssl/cert.pem? (y/n [n]) y
```

but then it gives error:

```
mv: rename cacert.pem to /private/etc/ssl/cert.pem: Permission denied
```

can someone help?